# How to prevent add new files of specific type in TFS

Tags: tfs

We're moving our web projects from aspx to cshtml.

We want to prevent users to add new aspx files to TFS, but we don't want to prevent to edit existing aspx files.

Is that possible?

We're using TFS 2012.

Comment: Did you check the .tfignore option? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible through a custom check in police that would be more hassle than it is worth.

You would be better with a code review and post moderate the issue. Get together with the coders and express the new policy and ideas. Get everyone on board, then post moderate for deviations.